# Different overlap effect for WPF Canvas Rectangles

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, rectangles

I need to have different stacking effect of opacity in canvas.

I am creating dynamically some Rectangles with mouse events on Canvas with opacity set to 0.6  with using different colors of Fill.

When the Rectangles overlapping each other the opacity changed in overlaped region.

It's okay for me if the rectangles have different colours, but I want to didn't have this effect when rectangles have the same colour.And if they have same colours I need the same opacity in the overlaped region .

Comment: Then set the Opacity of the Canvas.

Comment: I have edited your question. The description of the `[Canvas]` tag clearly states "don't use this for WPF". People get confused and give HTML5 answers.